# pipe input to bash script (to translate text)

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm trying to pu together a bash script to use [mymemmory](https://mymemory.translated.net/) api to translate text. I want it to be able to translate single lines and multiple line by pipeing into it.

This is the script (`mytrans`) so far (I'm using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq)):

```
#!/bin/bash

key=apikey
mail=themail

translate_line()
{
for x in "$@"; do
    totranslate="$totranslate%20$x"
done
totranslate=${totranslate:3}

url="https://api.mymemory.translated.net/get?q=$totranslate&langpair=en-US%7Ces-ES&of=json&key=$thekey&de=$mail"

translated_text=$(curl -s $url | jq-linux64 '.responseData.translatedText' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
echo $translated_text
}

if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
        while IFS= read line; do
            echo $line
            translate_line $line
        done
else
        translate_line "$@"
fi
```

It works fine if i run it on a simple line, or if I pipe a simple line. The problem is with multiple lines. Example:

```
$mytrans hello world
hello world
hola mundo
$echo bye | mytrans
bye
adios

$echo hello world > dd
$echo bye >> dd
$cat dd | mytrans
hello world
hola mundo
bye
lo bye mundo
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the function `translate_line()`, you should declare `local` or initialize `totranslate=""`, so that this it does not increase at each call.